# Xamarin iOS: How to load WebP from filepath

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, webp, ffimageloading

My project is Xamarin iOS project.
I tried to load the image using ffimageloading nuget package using the below:

```
var fileURL = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("test", "webp");
ImageService.Instance.LoadFile(fileURL).Into(imageView);
```

I even used the other available methods like embeddedResource, LoadURL, LoadFileFromApplicationBundle but in vain.

None of the above work and the imageView is empty. The same code seems to work fine for any GIF/png filetype.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does iOS natively support WebP?

Comment: Safari doesn't support it. But their GitHub page says it supports webp- https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading

Answer (score 0):

After hours of struggle:

It can be done using the dependent library of ffimageloading called as WebP.Touch(1.0.8):

```
    WebP.Touch.WebPCodec decoder = new WebP.Touch.WebPCodec();
    var fileURL = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("imageName", "webp");
    return decoder.Decode(fileURL);
```

Hope it helps someone.